# boost::static_visitor with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

```
typedef boost::variant<int, double> Type;
class Append: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(int)
    {}

    void operator()(double)
    {}

};

Type type(1.2);
Visitor visitor;
boost::apply_visitor(visitor, type);
```

Is it possible to change the visitor such that it receives extra data as follows:

```
class Append: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(int, const std::string&)
    {}

    void operator()(double, const std::string&)
    {}
};
```

This string value changes during the lifetime of the Append object. Passing the string in via the constructor is not an option in this case.

Comment: Why it's not an option? You could create another Append object with different strings in case that changes.

Comment: At which time will the string value change? I don't see why it cannot be done with a constructor neither.

Comment: @KennyTM The Append class takes a number of dependencies via its constructor. If I reconstruct the Append object within my class, then this class will also need to take all the dependencies used by Append via its constructor. I had hoped that my class would simply take an Append object via its constructor.

Comment: @Baz: You can take an `Append` object in the constructor, and then set particular values inside the `Append` object before each call, without even needing to know about any of the other dependencies.

Comment: @Mankarse Yes this is what I was thinking of doing but its seems a little like a hack since one might forget to set the values before applying the visitor.

Comment: @Baz: You could make a helper function that first sets the relevant part of the `Visitor`, and then calls `apply_visitor`. I can't think of a way to enforce it in the type system, but you could keep a `bool` around that tracks whether the helper function has been called, and asserts if it hasn't.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "additional argument" that gets given to each call is the `this` pointer. Use it to pass whatever additional information that you need:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
typedef boost::variant<int, double> Type;
class Append: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(int)
    {}

    void operator()(double)
    {}
    std::string argument;
};

int main() {
    Type type(1.2);
    Append visitor;
    visitor.argument = "first value";
    boost::apply_visitor(visitor, type);
    visitor.argument = "new value";
    boost::apply_visitor(visitor, type);
}
```

Comment: If necessary the member need not be an `std::string` but can be e.g. an `std::string*` that can thus be rebound.

Comment: @LucDanton: Indeed -- there are many possible variations on this general idea, depending on the exact needs of the situation.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to bind the extra arguments. You visitor class could look like this:

```
class Append: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(const std::string&, int)
    {}

    void operator()(const std::string&, double)
    {}
};
```

Call it like so:

```
std::string myString = "foo";
double value = 1.2;
auto visitor = std::bind( Append(), myString, std::placeholders::_1 );
boost::apply_visitor( visitor, value );
```

Answer (score 1):

This one solves your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

typedef boost::variant<int, double> Type;
typedef boost::variant<const std::string> Extra;
class Append: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(const int& a1, const std::string& a2) const {
        std::cout << "arg 1 = "<< a1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "arg 2 = "<< a2 << "\n";
    }

    void operator()(const double& a1, const std::string& a2) const {
        std::cout << "arg 1 = "<< a1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "arg 2 = "<< a2 << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Type type(1.2);
    Extra str("extra argument");
    boost::apply_visitor(Append(), type, str);
}
```

Here is a working <kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d53a98fed41d5fa)</kbd>. You can send extra arguments - as many as you want. The restriction is that they must be wrapped inside boost::variant. However the compiler optimizes away the variants with single type inside. If you want more than two arguments you have to `#include <boost/variant/multivisitors.hpp>`, see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html